# Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 broke apt

Tags: apt, 18.04, upgrade

#### How I got to where I am now:

I started the upgrade from Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 to 18.04.

Everything went fine until I was asked to reboot.

It got stuck at displaying `/dev/sdb6: clean 723689/3620864 files, 11918552/14478592 blocks`.
I switched into tty4.
There it said

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS....
...
...
*** System restart required ***...
...
```

So following some other Ask Ubuntu answers I tried

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

which didn't work. Then I did

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a  --force-depends
```

After that, I did

```
sudo apt --fix-broken
```

Then I rebooted. It booted correctly into Ubuntu GNOME.
I did `apt update`

#### The actual problem:

`apt` seems to be broken:
When I do `apt upgrade` it returns:

```
Some package could not be installed. This may mean
that you have requested an impossible situatio
or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required
packages have not been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat : Conflicts: packagekit
                               Conflicts: packagekit:i386
E: Broken packages
```

How could I fix that?

If you need more information, feel free to ask.

(Also, if this is somehow important: DNS wasn't working until I manually added `8.8.8.8` to `resolv.conf`)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Looks like `kicad-library` it's not present in any official repository, did you install one or more PPAs? If that's the case, they should be upgraded to the new version, as they won't get upgraded automatically when changing versions.

Comment: I could remove the kicad part by doing `apt install kicad`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the packages that give you errors, and then retry:

```
sudo apt purge python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade # to make sure that any remaining packages get updated
```

After that, you should also do

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

to remove any stale package that is no more needed in the new version.

As always, it *might* help to do

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

again after `apt update` works correctly.

Comment: So it is safe to remove that specific package?

Comment: I did what you said. After a reboot I can't use the normal GNOME anymore. Only GNOME Classic works. If login into to normal GNOME, the screen turns black and the login page opens again.

Comment: (running apt upgrade returns: https://pastebin.com/nhyssLaE )